# Knockout Two-way Bind Nested Array

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having troubles getting the binding working for a nested array. The values are displaying correct when the page first loads, but when I make edits, bound objects do not update.

I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/coverbeck/qCzT6/1/.

My HTML is this:

```
<body>
    <ul>
<!-- ko foreach: {data: cities, as: 'city'} -->
        <li>
           <input data-bind="value: city.name"/>
           <span data-bind="text: city.name"></span>
        </li>
    <ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: neighborhoods, as: 'neighborhood'} -->
        <li>
            <input data-bind="value: neighborhood"/>
            <span data-bind="text: neighborhood"></span>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
</body>
```

And my JavaScript is:

```
var sf = {name: ko.observable('San Francisco'),
          neighborhoods: ko.observableArray([
                ko.observable('Haight'), 
                ko.observable('Bayview'), 
                ko.observable('Marina')
           ])
         }; 
var ny = {name: ko.observable('New York'),
          neighborhoods: ko.observableArray([
                ko.observable('Hells Kitchen'), 
                ko.observable('Times Square')
            ])
          };

var cities = ko.observableArray([sf, ny]);
var viewModel = { cities: cities };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When I modify city names, the corresponding span element updates. When I modify neighborhood names, the corresponding span element does not update.

I asked a similar question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353417/knockout-data-bind-to-array-element-only-half-working), and the answer worked. I seem to be running into the same problem all over again, except this time it's a nested array where I'm seeing the problem. I tried the fix from that answer against the nested array, but it didn't seem to make a difference in this case.

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: Man, your code formatting is atrocious. Can you even read that?

Comment: "Atrocious" seems a little harsh, but I updated the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where your problem is coming from, but it can be solved like this:

```
var ny = {name: ko.observable('New York'), 
          neighborhoods: ko.observableArray([
              new neighborhood('Hells Kitchen'), 
              new neighborhood('Times Square')])};

function neighborhood(name) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

Then you bind foreach `neighborhoods` and then bind to `name`. The problem might be that it doesn't like the observable that doesn't have a name?

Working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qCzT6/2/)